# Python / closing is not defined

Tags: python

I try to follow the [instructions of the scpclient](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scpclient).

I wrote the following code:

```
import paramiko
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.load_system_host_keys()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.WarningPolicy())
client.connect("my_ip", username="root", password="password")
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('display version')
with closing(Write(client.get_transport(), '.')) as scp:
    scp.send_file("/tmp/myfile", remote_path="/tmp")
client.close()
```

But I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ssh.py", line 11, in <module>
    with closing(Write(client.get_transport(), '.')) as scp:
NameError: name 'closing' is not defined
```

What can be the reason?

Comment: You have not defined `closing`.

Comment: Where do you think `closing` is defined - it isn't a python built in function,  so I assume it is actually meant to be `<name>.closing`  - where <name> is some module

Answer (score 4):

You need to import it: [`from contextlib import closing`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.closing)